# Excel VBA ByRef argument type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a procedure that captures when a cell has been selected and simply returns the cell column and row. I am getting a 'ByRef argument type mismatch' error but it doesn't make sense. See below screenshot:

[image]

The issue seems to be with the iRow variable. As far as I can see it is an integer and never ceases to be an integer. Why is the compile error occurring?

Please help. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: In future, please include your **code** in the question, not just a **picture** of your code.  (In this case the mistake was so obvious that people didn't need to debug the code, but usually people need to be able to copy/paste your code into their computer in order to test it, and they shouldn't be forced to retype it before they can help you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you have declared iRow as `Variant`. Unlike VB.Net, you will have to declare all variables explicitly. Anything which is not declared will be taken as a `Variant`

Change the line

```
Dim iRow, iCol As Integer
```

to

```
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
```