# How do I clear up this ByRef argument type mismatch error when inserting formula into cell?

Tags: vba

I am trying to punch a formula into a cell, referencing a function ConvertToLetter to do so (seen in my code). However, running ConvertToLetter doesn't seem to work, returning the titular error when I try to run it with a highlight on "firstVideoRow". My thought is that this program is not returning a string, but that's just a guess.

I've already tried to initialize the ConvertToLetter variables elsewhere, but that doesn't work either.

```
Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Long) As String
   Dim iAlpha As Long
   Dim iRemainder As Long
   iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
   iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
   If iAlpha > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
   End If
   If iRemainder > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
   End If
End Function
```

...

```
Range(Cells(lastRow + 3, 4)).Formula = "=AVG(" & ConvertToLetter(firstVideoRow) & CStr(4) & ":" & ConvertToLetter(lastRow) & CStr(4) & ")"
```

Comment: What version of excel are you using that has an `AVG` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConvertToLetter` wants a `Long` by reference. Apparently you [did not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44229503/11683) declare `firstVideoRow` and/or `lastRow` as `Long`, so you get the error.

You [could](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16612000/11683) ask for a `Long` by value so that it is implicitly converted for you:

```
Function ConvertToLetter(ByVal iCol As Long) As String
```

But actually what you want to do is switch to the R1C1 notation:

```
Cells(lastRow + 3, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVG(R4C" & firstVideoRow & ":R4C" & lastRow &")"
```

Comment: What is AVG supposed to do?

Comment: @user10959770 I have no idea and it does not matter. The error does not come from the use of `AVG`. If such function does not in fact exist in the OP's environment, there will be a `#NAME!` error that is unrelated to the byref argument mismatch.

Comment: Thanks very much for the R1C1 thing! And yes, I meant AVERAGE, not AVG.

Comment: @user10959770 it scans your computer for viruses, allegedly ;-)